# Custom activity image background

Tags: android

I want to apply a custom image to the background of an activity but whenever I select the image, it has compressed the picture causing the picture's quality to reduce. Is there any image size that I should use to avoid that? or any trick or something.

Comment: Provide MCVE. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should set the image with and heights according to respective screen sizes

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Here's a link where you can see how you can support different screen sizes

Comment: Will do that. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark my answer as accepted if it helps you

Comment: I've provided the answer and for more clarity reference is necessary